# Append numpy matrix to binary file without numpy header

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I continously receive new data as numpy matrices which I need to append to an existing file. Structure and data type of that file are fixed, so I need python to do the conversion for me.

For a single matrix, this works:

```
myArr = np.reshape(np.arange(15), (3,5))
myArr.tofile('bin_file.dat')
```

But suppose I'd want to keep appending the existing file with more and more arrays, then `numpy.tofile` will overwrite any content it finds in the file, instead of appending.

I found that I could also keep doing this:

```
bfile = open('bin_file.dat', 'ab')
np.save(bfile, myArr)
bfile.close()
```

which successfully appends to the binary file. But `numpy.save` on the other hand does not store the raw binary data, but also saves a header (I assume) which makes the file unreadable by foreign software (I need raw binary with `float32`).

Reading in the existing content of the file with `numpy.fromfile`, appending my data and saving it again is not an option, since the file becomes very large and all the I/O would take forever to process.

Is there anything like an `append` mode for `numpy.tofile`? Are there other possibilities I am currently missing?

Comment: Did you hear about `hdf5`?http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html

Comment: @RedEyed: On first sight, this doesn't look like a solution to my problem. Does `hdf5` allow me to save raw binary files that can be read by other software?

Comment: Okay. First of all, let's define your format.
What does `binary` mean?
Everything is binary here(numpy, hdf5) not text

Comment: Okay, I guess, binary is sequence of 4 bytes (float32) as said above.
So, your problem is that, file becomes very large and its hard to read it.
In that case, why do you ask about `append` ? You've already achieved appending. The problem is in reading large binary file, right?

Comment: (Edit). Not quite. appending only worked with numpy.save, but that stores header information within the file (which I can't read with the software we have to use for analyzing the data). Size of the file is not the problem. But I cannot reopen and save the file anytime I append it. That would take way too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to append to a `tofile` file:

```
In [344]: with open('test1',mode='ba+') as f:
     ...:     np.arange(3).tofile(f)
     ...:     np.arange(5).tofile(f)
     ...:     
In [345]: np.fromfile('test1',dtype=int)
Out[345]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This saves the array data without shape or dtype information.  So the load has to specify `dtype`.  And any reshaping is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I managed to get the desired result by saving several binary files and concatenating them in PowerShell `copy /b`, but this is way nicer. It works great!