# How to write ndarray to .npy file iteratively with batches

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I am generating large dataset for a machine learning application, which is a numpy array with shape `(N,X,Y)`. Here `N` is the number of samples, `X` is the input of a sample and `Y` is the target of a sample. I want to save this array in the `.npy` format. I have many samples (`N` is very large) so that the final dataset is about 10+ GB. This means that I cannot create the whole dataset and then save it, as it will flood my memory.

Is it possible to instead to write batches of `n` samples iteratively to this file? So, I want to append for example batches of 256 samples to the file at once (`(256,X,Y)`).

Comment: I don't think it's possible: repeated writing to the same file will create new arrays in the file, see [last example in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). The only option I see is to use a csv file or the like using `savetxt` where you can append new rows.

Comment: @Stef I definitely think it is possible, but indeed not with `np.save`. It probably involes the `tofile()` function instead, which allows you to write binaries. I'm still trying to get it work, but this question & answer seem promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086704/append-numpy-matrix-to-binary-file-without-numpy-header/51089256

Comment: I guess it would be nice to have a solution implemented and officially supported by numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out it is possible using [np.tofile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) and [np.fromfile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). Note the code below still assumes you have the whole array in memory, but you can of course change the batches to be generated dynamically.

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000;
X = 10;
Y = 1;
my_data = np.random.random((N, X, Y));
print(my_data[700,:,:])

batch_size = 10;

with open('test.dat',mode='wb+') as f:
    i = 0;
    while i < N:
        batch = my_data[i:i+batch_size,:,:]
        batch.tofile(f)

        i += batch_size;

x = np.fromfile('test.dat',dtype=my_data.dtype)

x = np.reshape(x, (N,X,Y))
print(x[700,:,:])
```

As @hpaulj mentioned, this file cannot be loaded with `np.load`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on numpy's implementaion of `save` to write a standard `npy` file including shape and type information:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib as npl

a = np.random.random((30, 3, 2))
a1 = a[:10]
a2 = a[10:]

filename = 'out.npy'
with open(filename, 'wb+') as f:
    header = npl.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(a1)
    npl.format.write_array_header_1_0(f, header)
    a1.tofile(f)
    a2.tofile(f)
    f.seek(0)
    header['shape'] = (len(a1) + len(a2), *header['shape'][1:])
    npl.format.write_array_header_1_0(f, header)

assert (np.load(filename) == a).all()
```

This works for `C_CONTIGUOUS` arrays without Python objects.